# EventBus.subscribe() in SAPUI5

Tags: events, sapui5, subscribe

I am new to eventBus() function in SAPUI5.
I am using eventBus.publish() in Table.view.js controller to publish data & have used eventBus.subscribe() in MainPage.view.js controller. It is working fine.
But while I try to implement eventBus.subscribe() in another controller ("Feed.view.js"), it is not working. Why is it so?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Is the Feed view instantiated?

Comment: I am using sap.ui.ux3.Shell() & Feed.view.js is one of the pages in the Shell

Comment: `Table.view` is the part of `MainPage.view` ? If yes, you need to make `Table.view` be part of core view. Otherwise there is no event emitter because `Table.view` is destroyed.

Comment: Sorry but I am not getting what you are trying to say!!

Comment: Please show us the code parts where you publish and subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of you problem is likely one of the following:

- You are not using the same EventBus in all cases (e.g. in one case
  you use the `sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus()`, and in another case you
  use your component's `oComponent.getEventBus()`)
- You are not using the same channel
- You are not using the same event ID

Please check this, and if it doesn't help post more of your code.